# Hide / show element if text is / isn't to long in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a search bar in which I want to display search results next to search input field.

I wanted to make it smart, so if the search result is too long (in my case - if the span height is bigger than container), jQuery hides results from search bar container and displays box underneath.

Also in CSS I hide the search result span when the screen width reached 400 as there is no way to fit anything in anyway

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 400px) {        
    div.results {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

So the code works properly first, once you shrink the screen down, when span gets bigger than the container, it's being hidden and new div shows. Now I encounter 2 problems:

1. When the screen get's smaller than 400px and div gets switched off in css, because it's not there, it doesn't get the height data and therefore jQ is not launched. I tried to add `|| $divResults.length() === 0` line to `if` statement but that doesn't do the job either.
2. After shrinking down the screen and applying `> 30` statement, when I want to make the screen bigger again. Span result height is now not bigger than container, but I'm stuck in `> 30` code, and not really sure how to stop that condition and get back to the state before screen got shrinked down.

(3. Bonus issue is that sometimes results spam disappears because it gets to big but new div is not being launched, but that's not a critical issue, as it only happens on fairly narrow pixel gap range)

Here's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w20jf4u9/)

HTML:

```
<div id="container-cpanel">

    <div class="search-header">
        <div class="search-header-input">Search for friends:</div>
        <div class="results" style="background: grey"> <span>no search results for... </span>                                         </div>
    </div>

    <div id="container">

        <div id="results-popup" class="popup"> 
            <span>No search results for:</span>    
            <div class="button-close"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQ:

```
$(document).ready(responsive);
$(window).on('resize', responsive);

function responsive() {

    $('#results-popup').hide();

    var $divResults = $('div.results'),
        $spanResults = $('div.results span'),
        $resultsPopup = $('#results-popup'),
        spanResultsHeight = $spanResults.height();

    if (spanResultsHeight > 30) {

        $spanResults.hide();
        $resultsPopup.appendTo('#container-cpanel').fadeIn(400);

    };

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about that:

```
if (spanResultsHeight > 30 || $divResults.is(':hidden')) {

    $spanResults.hide();
    $resultsPopup.appendTo('#container-cpanel').fadeIn(400);

    } else {

    $spanResults.show();

};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w20jf4u9/1/)

Comment: I was THAT close ;) Thanks!